# How to create a SSL certificate for a website being hosted in a IIS 7?

Tags: windows, ssl, https, iis-7, certificate

I'm trying to create a SSL certificate for an "old“ website being hosted in an IIS 7 server. The website currently uses `http`, but I will like to start using `https`. I'm trying to find the best and easiest way to do this, but I'm getting confused in what to do and how to do it.

I have tried reference articles like this `https://www.digicert.com/kb/csr-ssl-installation/iis-7.htm#ssl_certificate_install` and some other youtube videos, but

1. I cannot event get the application DigiCert to open on the windows machine (to buy a certificate)
2. It seems I have to buy the certificate for ~ $200 ??

Are there any (free ?) or other methods to make my current `http` site use `https`. I know `certbot` does this for me on `nginx` servers, but how to accomplish this on a windows server?

Thanks

Comment: IIS 7 is end of life. Use a search engine please if you want tool recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a self-signed certificate from https://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/.

You can also request a trusted certificate for free from Certbot.

Or you purchase it from a trusted CA. Eg. Sectigo.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is using [certbot from Let's encrypt](https://certbot.eff.org). You can choose Windows there as system. Also see https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-generate-a-ssl-certificate-for-iis-7-0-or-7-5/29467 .